# Biharmonic heat flow on compact manifolds

Tags: reference-request, ap.analysis-of-pdes, parabolic-pde, heat-equation, green-function

Consider $\partial _t u (t,x) = -\partial _x ^4 u$ on a compact manifold, or even a special specific one like the torus.

Are there any estimates on the Green function (bihamornic heat kernel), for either short or long time? Is there eventual positivity? I could really find no references to this problem whatsoever.

*Remark:* There are some results on $\mathbb{R}^d$ regarding eventual positivity and decay rates, see [Ferrero, Gazzola, and Grunau](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.516.2000&rep=rep1&type=pdf), and a lot about the time-indpendent problem on compact domains, see [this monograph](http://www.mi.uni-koeln.de/~gsweers/pdf/GGS.pdf).

Comment: Eventual positivity should follow from the main results in [this article](https://doi.org/10.1007/s00020-018-2478-y). (I only have my mobile phone available right now, but I can provide a detailed reference later).

Comment: @JochenGlueck thanks. Does it give quantitative estimates, e.g., on the time of eventual positivity of the decay rate?

Comment: @Bombyxmori I really want to know whether anything can be said quantitatively about the Green function, similar to estimates one has on the harmonic (heat) kernel for short times.

Comment: @AmirSagiv: No, this article does not contain quantitative estimates for the time of eventual positivity or for decay rates. It focusses on qualitative criteria for an operator semigroup to be (uniformly) eventually positive (Theorem 3.1 and, for the case of self-adjoint semigroups on $L^2$-spaces, Corollary 3.5).

Comment: @JochenGlueck Thank you. It does help  a lot. Do you know on any quantitative estimates?

Comment: @AmirSagiv: Unfortunately I don't. At least for the one-dimensional torus, it should be possible to write down the eigenvalue expansion explicitly, and maybe one can get explicit estimates from this. (But admittedly, this is just a long shot.)

Comment: @JochenGlueck is the eigenvalue expansion for the torus just standing waves $\psi_{\lambda} (x) = e^{i\lambda ^{1/4} x}$?

Comment: @AmirSagiv: Yes. More precisely (if we write the one-dimensional torus as $\mathbb{R} / 2\pi\mathbb{Z}$): the eigenvalues are the numbers $0$ (whose eigenspace is the set of constants functions) and the numbers $-k^4$ where $k=1,2,\dots$ (and the eigenspace for $-k^2$ is two-dimensional and spanned by $x \mapsto e^{ikx}$ and $x \mapsto e^{-ikx}$).